# Do I need load and store memory barriers (fences), or is just a store barrier enough?

Tags: c++, lock-free, memory-fences

I've got `std::atomic<int>* key, *val`;

I want to write to both. There are multiple threads reading these values concurrently. I want to ensure that val is written before key. That is ensure that if readers see the new value of key, they MUST also see the new value of val. It's fine to see the new val with the old key, or to see both of the old values. The code must work on relaxed processor architectures (ARM).

Normally it is enough to do (in-order) `val->store(x, relaxed), key->store(y, release)` and load them with (in-order) `key->load(acquire), val-load(relaxed)`. On ARM, I believe acquire inserts a load barrier and release inserts a store barrier. However, for various reasons, I'm not using atomic to read val, and using a barrier on every read access would be too expensive.

Is it possible to use just a store barrier (sfence on x86) between the two stores to enforce ordering? Remember seeing stale values for key and val is perfectly fine, all I want to ensure is that if the new value for key is seen by another core, it must also see the new value of val. The reader always reads key first and the read of val is dependent on the value of the key (even it's memory address is), so I don't believe it's possible for either compiler or processor to re-order the loads such that val is read before key. It would have to read key to even know where to look for val. I suspect it is this property that would allow the code to work without a load barrier.

Am I right?

Comment: *"However, for various reasons, I'm not using atomic to read val"* In your pseudo-code, you've written `val-load(relaxed)`. I'm a bit confused: do you read from `val` with an atomic load with relaxed memory order?

Comment: Could you clarify the situation in the final paragraph? If val is dependent upon key from the reader's perspective, then there is another data-structure in play here.

Comment: @halfflat Key is really one of a sequence of keys in a sorted array, and the address of val is determined by the result of a binary search over these keys. So if key is loaded, it must have been loaded before val. The load of val can't logically be re-ordered to before the load of key.

Comment: @dyp actually I always read val with load(acquire), but key is read with load(relaxed).

Comment: That... doesn't make much sense to me. An acquire-release synchronization only happens if you use the same variable, e.g. store with release memory order to `key`, then load from `key` with acquire. If you then use relaxed atomics to write+read from `val`, you should be fine.

Comment: @dyp I definately don't want to store key before val. Then it's possible a reader could see the new key with the old val, which is invalid. The other way around, old key, new val is ok. So I need to store val, then key, with a store fence between (probably just store release for both of them.) While I agree that normally you need to load key with acquire to make the acquire-release ordering work, I think I can relaxed load it here specifically because it's not possible for the loads to be re-ordered, so the load barrier would be redundant.

Comment: Ah, sorry about my example. -- I think reordering is not the only concern of the new standardized memory model. Specifically, a relaxed load can read *any* value in the modification order of the object which is newer or equally old than the last value loaded in this thread. I tend to think of that as separate caches per object, where a relaxed load might, or might not, synchronize that cache. This implies that you can't just use a relaxed load for both key and value, unless you rely on additional guarantees from your compiler for your platforms.

Comment: Here's a fixed example: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PYnHZRPhPrlYlxED Supposedly, you don't want to use that fence, or an atomic load with acquire every time. **Iff** the key is not changed back to an old key, or you don't mind reading the old value if that happens, this example should work because of [atomic.fences]p4 (for which I've marked the lines with the metasyntactic variables in my code).